# How to fix this java error- $javac LoginAssignment.java

Tags: java

I'm trying to run the below code, however, I'm getting this error.
I really don't know what is missing:

Here is the error
LoginAssignment.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
if(pWord[passCounter].equals(enteredpassword)){
^
symbol:   variable enteredpassword
location: class LoginAssignment
2 errors

---

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LoginAssignment {
 static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args){
 
   String[] uName = {"Sosman","Msmith", "Rjoe"};
   String[] pWord = {"P4word1", "987654", "cat234"};
   
   String enteredUsername;
   System.out.println("Enter your username");
   System.out.println("Available users: Sosman, Msmith, Rjoe");
   enteredUsername = input.nextLine();
   
   String enteredPassword;
   System.out.println("Enter your password");
   System.out.println("Available passwords: P4word1, 987654 , cat234");
   enteredPassword = input.nextLine();
   
        int userLength = uName.length;
        int userCounter;
        int userTest = 0;
        int userCorrect = -1;
        for(userCounter = 0; userCounter < userLength; userCounter++){
           if(uName[userCounter].equals(enteredUsername)){
           
           userTest =1;
           userCorrect = userCounter;
           }
        }
       
       int passLenght = pWord.length;
       int passCounter;
       int passTest = 0;
       int passCorrect = -2;
       for(passCounter = 0; passCounter < passLength; passCounter++){
       if(pWord[passCounter].equals(enteredpassword)){
       
       passTest =1;
       passCorrect = passCounter;
     }
       }
     if((userTest== 0|| passTest == 0) ||(userCorrect !=passCorrect))
        System.out.println("Username not fourd or password in incorrect");
     
     if(passTest == 1&& userTest == 1&& userCorrect == passCorrect)
        System.out.println("You are logged in as: " + uName[userCorrect]);
      }
         }
```

Comment: `enteredpassword` doesn't exist as a variable in that context.. but `enteredPassword` does. Note the capitalization.

Comment: Anyway, I strongly recommend that you use an IDE for writing Java code, it would be much easier to get errors and fix them. There are many of them, and some good ones are free as well, like eclipse (which I use for work) and IntelliJ (community edition). Have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors in your code are:

1. In the second `for` you typed `passLength` instead of `passLenght`. It's just a typo error, I suggest that you change the name of the variable, as the correct spelling is `passLength`
2. In the `if` inside the second for, you used `enteredpassword` instead of `enteredPassword`, thus another typo error.